# Is it possible to get username/last visited page after session timeout

Tags: java, spring, cookies, spring-security, httpresponse

In my application I have an `invalid-session-url` and I was wondering if it's possible to get the username in the `invalid-session-url`? If so please advise how to do that.

Comment: i don't think so.. there is no any method to get the value from expired session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can send cookie to user's web browser with value of his/her username when user is authenticated. When session is expired, you can still access that cookie. All you need to do is set its lifetime to be long enough.

You may implement your own `Filter`. I recommend extending `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. Overriding `Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` gives you access to cookies - you can add one with `HttpServletResponse.addCookie(Cookie cookie)`.

You can easily inject your own filter. More info about config: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-custom-filter

Also take into account that it can be insecure to send such a cookie. I don't see any other way to accomplish what you want.
But you can easily improve security of this solution by configuring `LogoutHandler`. There is an implementation of this interface `CookieClearingLogoutHandler`. You can use it to clear that cookie when user decides to logout manually.

```
<bean id="cookieClearingLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.CookieClearingLogoutHandler">
    <constructor-arg>
        <!-- Names of the cookies you want to remove when user logs out -->
        <list>
            <value>username</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/login"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <ref local="securityContextLogoutHandler"/>
            <!-- Inject it -->
            <ref local="cookieClearingLogoutHandler"/>
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: how to get that username in code ?  aslo what's the filterProcessesUrl ? and is it possible to get last page before session timeout ?

Comment: `filterProcessesUrl` specifies the URL that activates the actions in filter. For `logoutFilter` `filterProcessesUrl` specifies path that is responsible for getting request from user to log him/her out. When user "clicks" the URL, he/she is logged out.

Comment: More about cookies in Spring MVC: http://blog.vulab.com/2012/04/05/spring-mvc-3-creating-cookies-and-reading-cookies/

Comment: how can i get the username in this case in my java class ?

Comment: Check the last URL I posted in comment.

Comment: is it possible to get last visited url before session timeout ?